# Dynamically Count Null Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a little new at SQL so please bear with me. I am attempting to write some a query that will allow me to loop through an entire table and find the number of times null values appear in each column. This is easy to do the hard way by typing the following:

```
Select 
    SUM(CASE COL_1 WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COL_1_NULLS
   ,SUM(CASE COL_2 WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COL_2_NULLS
FROM TABLE1
```

This is easy but it can become arduous if you want to do this for multiple tables or if a single table has a lot of columns.

I'm looking for a way to write a query that passes a table name into it and then loops through each column in the defined table (possibly pulling the column name by ordinance via a join to a metadata view?) and then sums the number of nulls in the column. Before anyone jumps on the nitpick bandwagon please keep in mind that this basic idea could be used for more than just finding nulls. Any assistance with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic SQL for this.  That seems rather advanced for someone who describes themselves as "a little new".

Comment: You can query the sys.columns table (https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sql+server+loop+columns+in+a+table), but honestly, unless this is going to be used for a lot of tables it would be less effort to just hard code the column names.

Comment: I have no nitpick bandwagon about what you are doing but you mentioned looping multiple times. A select statement does not loop through all the rows. It finds the rows that meet the criteria. This type of thing would have to be done using dynamic sql as Gordon already suggested.

Comment: Maybe I should say new to SQL on this level, I've never attempted SQL on this level before but i'm jumping in with both feet. Regardless, thank you for the heads up and do you have any direction with regards to Dynamic SQL and my topic? I've run across it before in my searching today but I can't seem to find anything comparable to my current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql:

```
declare @custom_sql varchar(max)
set @custom_sql = 'SELECT null as first_row'
select
    @custom_sql = @custom_sql + ', ' +  'SUM(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ' + COLUMN_NAME + '_NULLS'
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'MYTABLE'

set @custom_sql = @custom_sql + ' FROM MYTABLE'

exec(@custom_sql)
```

You can also use the `COALESCE` term (just for a slightly different approach):

```
declare @custom_sql varchar(max)

select
    @custom_sql = COALESCE(@custom_sql + ', ', '') +  'SUM(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ' + COLUMN_NAME + '_NULLS'
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'users'

set @custom_sql = 'SELECT ' + @custom_sql

set @custom_sql = @custom_sql + ' FROM Users'

print @custom_sql

exec(@custom_sql)
```

Comment: This solution (I used the top one) works perfectly for me, now I just need to figure out exactly what is happening in that script and i'll be all set. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make a generic query, but you can always generate the script like this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select 1 as dummy'
select @sql = @sql + '
    , sum(case when [' + c.name + '] is null then 1 else 0 end) as [' + c.name + '_NULLS]'
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'TABLE1'

set @sql = @sql + ' from TABLE1'
select @sql
```

Then you can execute the result eg. with `exec sp_executesql @sql`

Answer (score 0):

For a cooler approach, you can use ISNULL to skip the first comma.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @tablename nvarchar(255) = 'xxxx'

Select @sql = ISNULL(@SQL + ',','')  + ' ' + COLUMN_NAME + '_count = Sum(case when ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' is null then 1 else 0 end)' + char(13)
From information_schema.columns
where table_name = @tablename

set @sql = 'Select' + @sql + ' From ' + @tablename

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I like this too, you can also use COALESCE to skip the first comma.

Comment: yes, isnull is a sql server specific function, whereas COALESCE is more standard sql.